# VBA -Delete data not in a given date range

Tags: vba, date

am attempting to remove data from a worksheet based on a given date range. On sheet "Grower Reporting" I have a small data set with dates in column L. The rest of the data are in columns N, M and O. In the same worksheet I have two cells that define the date range, cell "A2"=Start Date and cell "B2"= End Date. I am attempting to remove from my dataset any date & adjacent data that does not fall into the given date range.

Thanks to ARich and varocarbas for helping me get this far!

Here is what I have done (bear with me, I have a tenuous grasp of coding):

```
Sub delete_data()

Dim startDate As Date
Dim endDate As Date
Dim r_date As Date


startDate = Sheets("Grower Reporting").Range("a2").Value
endDate = Sheets("Grower Reporting").Range("b2").Value

Set r = Sheets("Grower Reporting").Range("L:L").Find(r_date, Range("L2"), _
LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchdirection:=xlNext)

If (r_date >= startDate And r_date <= endDate) Then

  r.Offset(0, -1).Value = " "

     End If

End Sub
```

The above code doesn't seem to do anything. I think I am on the right track but am in dire need of some guidance.

Comment: Is there a way? Sure. But what have you tried? I looked at your previous question and this code is identical to the marked answer there. You know... you are expected to do something by your own. What problem (getting the dates, comparing the dates, etc.) has you tried to address and why you weren't able to fix it? Also it is not clear what you mean with "returning" as far as your code does not return anything, just modify some cells.

Comment: I have tried defining two dates as variables but could not figure out the code compare the date range with the dates in column "I".

Comment: The code you have posted is not relevant for this problem (and was written by someone else); having it as a support is fine, but it does not prove your minimal understanding, attempted solutions, etc. Write the bits dealing with dates and, please, clarify what you meant with the data you want to return.

Comment: Also, sorry for the unclear terminology. I am a bit of a novice when it comes to programming.

Comment: I don't have any problem with the terminology as far as it is clear. "Return" implies a function where certain analysis is performed and certain value(s) (variable) is sent back to the caller. If you didn't mean that, just clarify what you want: "adding values to the cells as in my original code for the rows where the date's conditions are met"? -> not sure. The more detailed are your explanations the better. Please, write down what you have tried on the dates front and confirm what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I've edited the above code to show what I have so far. I am at a loss with anything more than defining the dates as variables. The macro as it is looks for data on "Grower Rejection Data" and based on the grower name selected in combobox1 and creates a short list in the "grower Reporting" sheet. I want the list it creates to only include data that occurred in the defined date range.

Comment: Yes, you are a bit lost :) OK. I will write a small code to help you (if I have understood properly what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform the checks inside the loop (for each row). Dates accept the same operators than numbers. Sample code:

```
If Not r Is Nothing Then
    Dim curDate As Date
    firstAddress = r.Address
    Do
        curDate = Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 9).Value 'Column I
        If (curDate >= d1 And curDate <= d2) Then
           Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 13).Value = r.Value
           Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 14).Value = r.Offset(0, -3).Value
           Sheets("Grower Reporting").Cells(i, 15).Value = r.Offset(0, 6).Value
           i = i + 1
           Set r = Sheets("Grower Rejection Data").Range("E:E").FindNext(r)
        End If
    Loop While Not r Is Nothing And r.Address <> firstAddress
End If
```

NOTE: this code assumes that all the inputs have the same (date) format. If this is not the case, you might have to rely on the `Format` function or affect the `Cell` properties. In case of dealing with different "Regional Settings" (e.g., computer in English from the UK and data from the US; where the date formats are different), you might get involved in some problematic issues.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I was looking for! I appreciate all of your help!

Comment: @user1437463 no problem. I hope that will help you to keep learning VBA and know how to face the problems.

Comment: I'm getting an error "Run-Time Error 91 Object variable or With Block variable not set". The error is occurring on line 13 of the above code. Should I paste what I have in my original question?

Comment: @user1437463 Better tell me the exact line. If your previous code was working, this version has also to work.

Comment: @user1437463 you missed the condition. But it is the same... the bits I introduced do not provoke any error by assuming right inputs. This code assumes that the "I" column contains dates. In any case, the error you report does not make any sense... See, let's speed up this process. Do you mind to upload the whole spreadsheet such that I can take a look at it and tell you what is wrong?

Comment: @user1437463 and with that (missing End If) your error does make sense. Add the End If (just copy my code as it is) and everything should work fine.

Comment: Ok, I have eliminated the error messages by adding the end if. However, the macro does not produce a list. The area where the list is supposed to appear is just blank. I re-posted the code above.

Comment: @user1437463 as said, I cannot do anything from here (without knowing the input data). This code is fine and works as expected. If it does not deliver what you want is because your conditions are different than what you said (column "I" does not contain dates or are of a different format or do not belong to the target span). Ideally, you should be able to debug this code (set up a break point in the condition and see why it does not go in; or confirm the values in column I); but I guess that the quickest option is letting me taking a look at it (= see the whole spreadsheet).

Comment: @user1437463 PS: bear in mind that this goes completely against what my help was meant for. I expected you to understand my code (and learn from it); but you are clearly looking for other thing (a working code now for a specific problem, without knowing what it does). I have started this and will complete it but want to let very clear that don't like it and that, in case of having known from this result, I wouldn't have helped you at all.

Comment: I will tinker with it to see what I can learn. I appreciate your help. I am a bit hesitant to share with you the workbook as it contains sensitive proprietary information.

Comment: @user1437463 No problem, but under these conditions I cannot be of further help. If, after working on it (and not fixing it), you find a specific sub-set of data which you don't mind to share, feel free to let me know. In any case, you should be able to find the problem by performing a simple debugging (your might take this as an excuse to learn to debug).

Comment: Again I truly appreciate your help. Please excuse my hastiness, I have been multi-tasking today and clearly was not analyzing and trying to understand the code you provided. After tinkering a bit I believe I have a better understanding of how to achieve the results I want.